# Querying for ACL on Linux

Tags: c, linux, acl

Is there any way to query ACLs on Linux programmatically? Given a file or directory, I have to check if an ACL exists for it and then find out the level of access granted to different users. All I could find on the net were the `getfacl` and `setfacl` command line utilities which are of no use to me. Also, what are the best practices I need to follow when working with ACLs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are in the `acl.h` header.  There are links out to each of the functions from [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/acl).

A few sample functions:

- [acl_create_entry](http://linux.die.net/man/3/acl_create_entry) - create a new ACL entry
- [acl_delete_entry](http://linux.die.net/man/3/acl_delete_entry) - delete an ACL entry
- [acl_get_entry](http://linux.die.net/man/3/acl_get_entry) - get an ACL entry

The functions are in libacl.